# How can I make a movie of the plotted function due to time (for t=0:0.1:2)?

Tags: matlab, plot, animated-gif, differential-equations, movie

I want to ask you how to make a movie of the plotted function due to time for t=0:0.1:2. In the code I wrote the formula of the differential equation (gif) after i wrote the formula of the coefficient (a). In the formula of gif i gave (x-v*t) instead of (x) in order to make it depending on the time (t). I plotted it of course, but just for a value of time. I'm stuck on how to make the plot for different time values between 0 and 2 with step width=0.1 as a movie. I hope that you can help me about that issue.

```
syms x;

  a=zeros(110,1);
  %stage 3

  v=1; %m/s
  gif=0;
  t=0;
  for i=1:1:110 

  a(i)=(2/50)*(int(x*sin((i*pi*x)/50),x,0,1)+int((2-x)*sin((i*pi*x)/50),x,1,2));
  gif =gif + a(i)*sin((i*pi*(x-v*t)/50));   

  end

  clear x
  figure(1)
  x=[-20 20];
  plot=fplot(gif,x);
  grid on
  xlabel('space');
  ylabel('phi(x)');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
syms x;

a=zeros(110,1);
%stage 3

v=1; %m/s
gif=0;
t=0;
for i=1:1:110

    a(i)=(2/50)*(int(x*sin((i*pi*x)/50),x,0,1)+int((2-x)*sin((i*pi*x)/50),x,1,2));
    gif =gif + a(i)*sin((i*pi*(x-v*t)/50));

end

clear x;
x = -20:20; % your x values
y = double(subs(gif,x)); % calculate your y values
figure; hold on; grid on;
xlabel('space');
ylabel('phi(x)');
for i = 1:length(x)-1
    plot(x(i:i+1),y(i:i+1),'b'); 
    pause(0.1) % pause to create a frame.
end
```

The basic idea is to have a loop that plots two points and a line at a time. use `pause(timeIntervalInSecond)` to pause and visually create a frame.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is very very slow. Dont use symbolic when not needed. and don't use variable name that is function name ('plot'). Thats how you should do it:

```
clear 
syms x k real
simp=@(f) simplify(f, 'Steps', 100, 'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints', true);
a=matlabFunction(simp((2/50)*(int(x.*sin((k.*pi.*x)/50),x,0,1)+int((2-x).*sin((k.*pi.*x)/50),x,1,2))));

clearvars -except a

gif=@(v,k,x,t)sum(a(1:k).*sin(((1:k).*pi.*(x-v.*t)/50)),2);

v=1;
gif_110=@(x,t)gif(v,110,x,t);

figure(1)
x=[-20:0.1:20]';
h=plot(x,gif_110(x,0));
grid on;xlabel('space');ylabel('phi(x)');

for t=0:0.1:2
    h.YData=gif_110(x,t);
    drawnow;
    pause(0.1);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers plays the movie directly, which may not be real-time, depending on the speed of your computer and the complexity of your function. As an alternative, you can record the movie and [play it](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movie.html) afterwards, which will play the movie with the desired speed.

```
% record the movie
F(frameCount) = struct('cdata',[],'colormap',[]);
for i=1:frameCount
    plot(.., ..) % plot your data
    drawnow
    F(i) = getframe;
end

% Play the movie one time with the correct frame speed
movie(F,1,1/dt);
```